# How to compare two json file and print report of differences

Tags: python, html, json, compare

I would like to compare two json files and prepare a report via python program. I used one of library which was available called jsoncompare

What I have tried:

```
from jsoncompare import jsoncompare as json_comp

json_comp.long = int
json_comp.unicode = str
json_comp.xrange = range



a = [
  {
    "Key": "Name",
    "Value": "node1"
  },
  {
    "Key": "owner",
    "Value": "jhonson"
  },
  {
    "Key": "managed",
    "Value": "yes"
  }
]

b = [
  {
    "Key": "Name",
    "Value": "node1"
  },
  {
    "Key": "owner",
    "Value": "jhonson"
  },
  {
    "Key": "managed",
    "Value": "No"
  }
]

# Compare respecting each array's order
json_comp.are_same(a, b)

print(json_comp.are_same(a, b)[1])
```

Output of above:

```
  Reason: Different values
Expected:
  "yes"
Actual:
  "No"

Reason: Different values (Check order)
Expected:
  {
      "Key": "managed",
      "Value": "yes"
  }
Actual:
  {
      "Key": "managed",
      "Value": "No"
  }
```

When both json matches then I am not getting any output, but even if matches, i need to print values and say Yes in Difference(Yes or No) column in report

Expected output in table format possibly html for example :

[image]

logic:

```
1)value for key Name starts with lowercase + value match  -- Yes
2)value for key Name starts uppercase but  value matches  -- No
3)for other keys When value does not match its - No
4)for other keys When value does match (irrespective of case) its - Yes
```

can some one suggest any better ways to do that, or any reference please.

Comment: If the json structure is fixed, like the one you mentioned above, why can't you simply loop over the keys and compare ? You already have your logic, so simple do an if else and print "true" or "false".

Comment: Are your keys the same?

Comment: yes keys are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your keys are the same, you can use pandas here:

```
import pandas as pd 

with open('a.json', 'r+') as f:
    data_a = json.load(f)
with open('b.json', 'r+') as f:
    data_b = json.load(f)
df_a = pd.json_normalize(data_a)
df_b = pd.json_normalize(data_b)
df = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df['diff'] = np.where((df['Key_x']=='Name') & (df['Value_x'].str.contains(r'^[a-z]')) & (df['Value_y'].str.contains(r'^[a-z]'))  & (df['Value_x']==df['Value_y']), 'No', 'Yes')
df['diff'] = np.where((df['Key_x']!='Name') & (df['Value_x']!=df['Value_y']), 'Yes', 'No')
print(df)

     Key_x  Value_x    Key_y Value_y diff
0     Name    node1     Name   node1   No
1    owner  jhonson    owner  wright  Yes
2  managed      yes  managed      No  Yes
```

You can convert this to html using:

```
df.to_html('test.html')
```

Comment: Thank you let me test, i have source json in file format, how can i read that file.json in above code ?,

Comment: Thank you very much,its works fine as thtml able , have two doubts , 1) does it compare case sensitive also in values ? in my OP actually i have key called Name, for that alone, if actual value in json2 is not in small case, diff should be false ..all other keys will be matached based on value (no case sensitive requried in value) for example if  Value_x is node1 and Value_y is Node1 then diff is false. 2) in html output i am getting index number also, can we avoid it..(that 0,1,2)

Comment: This is a case sensitive match. You would have to add multiple conditions for your first condition to work. Not hard at all, but I need to run, I will try after some time

Comment: No worries , thank your for your valuable suggestion... i will also try, you can reply when ever you have free time :)   except Name key, all other keys and values should be True irrespective of case match ...hmm

Comment: I added an edit. I'm using np.where for the conditions - 
`np.where(condition, value if true, value if false)`

Comment: np stands for numpy ?

Comment: Yes import numpy as np

Comment: yeah let me try

Comment: Hi, just observed these thing, for Key called Name, its doing non-case sentive match -- so should be reverse for this key should be case senstive match i.e if value_y for Name key if not in all lowercase then Diff is Yes  , for owner key, its doing case-sensitve. hmm..let me try to reverse the code...hmm

Comment: Thank you so much..you are just superb...hmm at last i got what i want, just jumbled yes or no  it works.. sorry one last final question...as of now, it suffices clearly requriment, what is the way if i need to compare Key_x and Key_y also ...and decide the Yes or No..

Comment: Just add another condition for that, in a new line similar to Value

Comment: HI can we rename coluname in above output ? i mean key_x, key_y,value_x,value_y as cola, colb .,colc, cold, something like that possible ?